# Eclipse shortcut to run launch files

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have some launch files for the project which i use to run from the Run Configurations.

Is there any way to create a keyboard shortcut to run particular launch file so that i can just press a key to launch?

I have tried from Preferences -> General -> Keys, but there i didn't found my required launch configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no way to assign a particular key sequence to a particular launch configuration. All you can do is to either:

- always launch the previously launched application.
- launch the active editor. If not launchable, launch the associated project
- launch the active editor. If not launchable, launch the previously launched application

This applies when you press <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>. You can always manually launch a particular file by doing Right Click Run As or <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> for java applications or <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> for JUnit tests.

From Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching:

[image]

Comment: I my case i will not open any class file to launch. I have created one New Configuration in Run Configurations which main class points to particular class so instead of opening the class every time and launching i will just use that configuration to launch the file.  So, for this configured launch how we can set an shortcut?

Comment: And i have different configurations like that in the Run Configurations.

Answer (score 2):

The last configuration used can be launched with f11 but you must enable Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Always launch the previously...

If you select "Launch the selected resource..." and "Always launch the previously..." first, it will try to launch the active editor and if it's not possible the last configuration launched.

I don't know if there is the possibility to assign shortcuts for the others.

Comment: Then in this case how we can run the current file?  If i use ctrl+F11 or F11 instead of executing the current class, the previous launched class will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

shortcut key to run android project in Eclipse is

Ctrl+F11